# Network Manager - VPN add button enabled but inside of it everything is grey

Tags: vpn, networking

[image]

I've been playing around with the network-manager trying to get it to connect to my VPN server. I got the Add button enabled, which seemed to be most people's problem, but inside it i find this, where everything else is grey. Can anyone help me? (Noob-alert so please if you can answer it in a way that average humans can understand too) Thnx :)